# JavaScript: Create a delete and status button dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently working on building a Library app. I am attempting to dynamically create rows of book info using an object array. I am having trouble creating a delete button for each row that will remove all the contents in that row as well as a checkmark button for each row indicating that book has been read.

```
<div class = "container">
    <div class = "header">

    </div>

    <div class = "books">
        <div class = "book">
            <form id = "Form" onsubmit = "event.preventDefault();">
                <label for = "fname">First Name:</label>
                <input type = "text" id = "fname" name = "fname">
                <label for = "lname">Last Name:</label>
                <input type = "text" id = "lname" name = "lname">
                <label for = "title">Title:</label>
                <input type = "text" id = "title" name = "title">
                <label for = "pages">Pages:</label>
                <input type = "number" id = "pages" name = "pages">
                <label for = "read">Read</label>
                <input type = "checkbox" id = "read" name = "read" value = "Read">

                <button class = "addBook" onclick = "addBookToLibrary(); clearInput()">Add Book</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id = "bookInfo">
        <div id = "firstName"></div>
        <div id = "lastName"></div>
        <div id = "bookTitle"></div>
        <div id = "pageNum"></div>
        <button id = "delete"></button>
    </div>

</div>
```

---

```
let myLibrary = [];
function Book(firstName, lastName, title, pages, read) 
{
    this.firstName = firstName
    this.lastName = lastName
    this.title = title
    this.pages = pages
    this.read = read
}

function addBookToLibrary() 
{
    var firstName = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    var secondName = document.getElementById("lname").value;
    var title = document.getElementById("title").value;
    var pages = document.getElementById("pages").value;
    var read = document.getElementById("read").value;
    const book = new Book(firstName, secondName, title, pages, read);
    myLibrary.push(book);
    console.log(myLibrary);
    displayBooks();
}


function displayBooks()
{
    let name1 = " ";
    let name2 = " ";
    let bookT = " ";
    let numPages = " ";
    
    for (i = 0; i < myLibrary.length; i++)
    {
        // bookDesc += myLibrary[i].firstName + " " + myLibrary[i].lastName + " " + myLibrary[i].title + " " + myLibrary[i].pages + '<br/>';
        // document.getElementById("bookInfo").innerHTML = bookDesc;
        name1 += myLibrary[i].firstName + '<br/>';
        document.getElementById("firstName").innerHTML = name1;
        name2 += myLibrary[i].lastName + '<br/>';
        document.getElementById("lastName").innerHTML = name2;
        bookT += myLibrary[i].title + '<br/>';
        document.getElementById("bookTitle").innerHTML = bookT;
        numPages += myLibrary[i].pages + '<br/>';
        document.getElementById("pageNum").innerHTML = numPages;
    }
}
```

I was originally planning to see if I can store the status button as another object into the array. That way, I can display the name, title, pages, and read status in one row.

Comment: share code as txt, not img

Comment: u can share your code by jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Andriu1510 Please don't encourage using external code hosts, the code should be included in the question as text. A "snippet" can be used if you want to include functional HTML/CSS/JS.